# Data.List intercalate for monads

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads

I'm writing a small parser using the [ReadP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html) module. I have this expression:

```
cmdExpr = string "create" <|> string "add" <|> string "another alias" <|> ...
```

I would like to abstract away the `<|>` operation, but I don't see how. Something like `intercalate`:

```
getExpr cmds = intercalateM (<|>) $ map string cmds
cmdExpr = getExpr ["create", "add", "another alias", ...]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `choice`:

```
Prelude Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP> cmds = ["create", "add", "another alias"]
Prelude Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP> :t choice $ map string cmds
choice $ map string cmds :: ReadP String
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a fold.

`<|>` is not a list element, it's an associative function taking two arguments.

You need to do something like this:

```
getExpr cmds = foldr1 (<|>) $ map string cmds
```

Note that using `foldr1` is a quick and dirty fix: it will throw an exception if given an empty list. The robust way would be to use `foldr` with some kind of null parser as the base case.

Comment: `foldr (<|>) empty` exists as `asum` - slightly hard to find because it's in Data.Foldable rather than with the definition of Alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect use-case for [`asumMap` in Relude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.6.0.0/docs/Relude-Foldable-Fold.html#v:asumMap):

```
getExpr cmds = asumMap string cmds
cmdExpr = getExpr ["create", "add", "another alias", ...]
```

If you're not using Relude but are using other third-party libraries, then there are other identical functions, such as [`altMap` in Util](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/util-0.1.14.0/docs/Util.html#v:altMap):

```
import Util (altMap)
getExpr cmds = altMap string cmds
cmdExpr = getExpr ["create", "add", "another alias", ...]
```

If you want to stick with Base, then you can use `asum` and `map` separately, [as David Fletcher mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126030/data-list-intercalate-for-monads#comment104481731_59126344):

```
import Data.Foldable (asum)
getExpr cmds = asum $ map string cmds
cmdExpr = getExpr ["create", "add", "another alias", ...]
```